# Hibernate 4.2.5.Final and Spring 3.2.4 - Alternatives to getHibernateTemplate().find(query, param);

Tags: java, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

We are in the process of  upgrading to hibernate 4.2.5.final and Spring 3.2.4 in the process we need to remove `getHibernateTemplate()` and use `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()`. I was just wondering if there is an alternative for `getHibernateTemplate().find(query, param);`? for examples there are lots of lots like the following in the project:

```
public List<T> findByQuery(String query, Object... params) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(query, params);
}

public List<T> findByQuery(String query, Object param) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(query, param);
}

public List<T> findByQuery(String query) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
}
```

and the methods calling them will be something like:

```
public List<GroupField> find(Group group) {
        return findByQuery("from GroupField where group = ? order by id asc", group);
    }
```

I can do something like as follow:

```
public List<T> findByQuery(String hql, Object... params) {
        Query  query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

        if (params !=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length ; i++) {
                query.setParameter (i, params[i]);
            }
        }
        return query.list();
    }
```

but then hibernate will complain about Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.

Any help would be appreciate it

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
Query queryObject = session.createQuery(queryString);
 for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  queryObject.setParameter(i, values[i]);
 }
}
queryObject.list();
```

Comment: Hi Sajan thanks for your answer, I have done something similar but I was looking for something in hibernate4 instead of creating the methods manually e.g.:  Query  query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

  if (param !=null){
   for (int i = 0; i < param.length ; i++) {
    query.setParameter (i, param[i]);
   }
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<T> result = query.list();
  if (result.size() == 0) {
   return null;
  }
  else if (result.size() > 1) {
   throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1);
  }
  else {
   return result.get(0);
  }